# Excel allowing deletion of cell contents of data validated cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation

I have a worksheet where only cells which should be edited are unlocked, and the whole worksheet is then protected. One of the cells where editing is permitted has data validation set, based on a 2 item list. Data validation is setup to allow a `List` and the appropriate range for the `Source`.

The validation works to a point, in that choosing one of the two options in the dropdown is accepted, and entering a value not contained in the list is declined.

The problem I'm having is that Excel is allowing me to delete the contents of said cell (which I do not want - I want it to always have one of the two values in the list). Within the data validation window, I have tried both checking and unchecking the `Ignore blank` checkbox, which doesn't seem to have any effect.

*Ideally*, I'd like to do this without the need for `VBA`, but will concede if it is the only way.

[Here is a link to an example workbook](https://hostr.co/VQjjgGZG7lNE) - for `Option4x`, you are permitted to choose either of the dropdown options, but not permitted to enter random text. However, you are also permitted to delete the contents of the cell (which I don't want).

[image]

Comment: Could you upload or provide the link of the Sheet for better understanding?

Comment: @RajeshS just added a link to an example workbook and added a screenshot

Comment: My first reaction. What I've noticed that Data Rage C5:L15 is unprotected, in Column C, Cell C9 has drop down list, working properly, the actual editable area is D6:L12, rest worksheet is protected. Now Tell me the problem!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Data Validation only checks whether the entered data is as per the rules/list or not. Since the Cell is editable that's the reason Excel allows you to Delete the entered data but not  allowing to write out of the list.*

If you don't allow the validated data to be deleted then you need to Disable the Delete key. The below written sample code will help you to prevent the exercises.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address <> "$C$9" Then Exit Sub
   If Len(Target.Value) = 0 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
          Application.Undo
        MsgBox "You can't Delete,,,!"
     Application.EnableEvents = True
   End If

End Sub
```

**NB:** Since Excel don't have any function could prevent the cell, in this case only VBA will work.

Comment: Thanks - the code provided wasn't performing as I had hoped, but did lead me along the right lines. Shame the functionality isn't built in, but if this is how it has to be done then so be it. I've suggested an edit and will mark as accepted if/when the edit is approved.

Comment: Nice to hear from you @JonnyWright. Through Data Validation we may put a check on NOT TO LEAVE the CELL Blank, but in case of NOT DELETE , the Key Deactivation is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable relying on the Data Validated cell's "Ignore Blanks" property, the following is much easier to maintain...

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)    

    If Target.Validation.IgnoreBlank = False And Len(Target.Value) = 0 Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Application.Undo
            MsgBox "This cell can't be blank.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Value Required"
            Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
```

```
End Sub
```

The desired behavior will be enforced on any data-validated cell for which you have indicated that blanks should not be ignored...

[image]

Doing it this way, you don't have to hard-code any ranges.